# What is the best approach to deploy an outlook add-in?

Tags: deployment, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have built an outlook add-in which extracts the details of a mail like sender, subject, the body of the mail, etc and shares it to another messaging app. It is similar to "share to teams" outlook add-in. I want it to deploy it mainly to get a permanent redirect uri for the idp authentication within the addin to login to the messaging app, and then thinking about deploying it for the usage by our clients.

i found these two to be helpful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure#step-3-create-a-web-app-in-azure-using-the-azure-portal

and [Publish your add-in using Visual Studio - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-visual-studio)
but still a little skeptical on which one would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best way of deploying Office web add-ins. You have found already the manual how to deploy the add-in from VS manually. But it really depends on your conditions and preferences. Consider a web add-in like a regular web application in that matter. You may consider using CI/CD tools that can automatically deploy your changes tested and merged, for example.